# "Incorrect signature" from FBVideoUpload request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I'm getting an "Incorrect signature" error when uploading a video through FBConnect (version at https://github.com/zoul/facebook-ios-sdk/). See below.

Any ideas how to debug this?

Is there a working example for uploading a video through FBConnect?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The code:

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil];
_facebook.forceOldStyleAuth = TRUE;
[_facebook authorize:APP_ID permissions:permissions delegate:_facebookDelegate];

...

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dreamall" ofType:@"m4v" inDirectory:@"/"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
FBVideoUpload *upload = [[FBVideoUpload alloc] init];
upload.accessToken = _facebook.accessToken;
upload.apiKey = API_KEY;
upload.appSecret = SECRET;
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"test", @"title",
                               @"upload testing", @"description",
                               nil];
[upload startUploadWithURL:url params:params delegate:self];
```

The response:

```
<error_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">
  <error_code>104</error_code>
  <error_msg>Incorrect signature</error_msg>
  <request_args list="true">
    <arg>
      <key>description</key>
      <value>upload testing</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>v</key>
      <value>1.0</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>api_key</key>
      <value>...</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>method</key>
      <value>facebook.video.upload</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>session_key</key>
      <value>41ab9717c61b70a34a8e48d4.3-100000419172530</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>sig</key>
      <value>bca612d495400136f1847f2bc6907525</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>title</key>
      <value>test</value>
    </arg>
  </request_args>
</error_response>
í£|<€_Y†gÊˇ¯ZÓzì&Àle4:∫Ù6V-Fn#vÂΩ'‚¥gƒ˙Y†ˇOáeyœn,≠ˇŒX≤Ÿ˘¡¬6G˛éÊ]÷FùC¯7˘JêÁW˙∫nÂﬁ${(;∑.L‰¯õßÏAüˆ—6Û{ˆhu|ûﬁ± •ìn£hﬁÇç£÷¥GÃ…˛Ü·B:up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My facebook app was not set to "Desktop" mode. That's why the authentication didn't work. See:

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/wiki/DesktopMode

Unfortunately, they removed this option from Facebook's developer site so it's not possible to get the current version of FBVideoUpload working with a new app.

I've modified FBVideoUpload to use the new Graph API instead of the old REST API. See below. I'll get in touch with the developer of FBVideoUpload.

```
//static NSString *const kAPIURL = @"http://api-video.facebook.com/restserver.php";
static NSString *const kAPIURL = @"https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos";

...

/*
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:userParams];
[params setObject:@"1.0" forKey:@"v"];
[params setObject:@"facebook.video.upload" forKey:@"method"];
[params setObject:[self sessionID] forKey:@"session_key"];
[params setObject:apiKey forKey:@"api_key"];
[params setObject:[self signatureForParams:params] forKey:@"sig"];
[params setObject:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL] forKey:[movieURL lastPathComponent]];
[[FBRequest getRequestWithParams:params httpMethod:@"POST" delegate:delegate requestURL:kAPIURL] connect];
*/

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:userParams];
[params setObject:accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
[params setObject:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL] forKey:[movieURL lastPathComponent]];
[FBRequest getRequestWithParams:params httpMethod:@"POST" delegate:delegate requestURL:kAPIURL];
```

Answer (score 1):

For me FBVideoUpload works fine so I put my code here :

```
m_Facebook = [[Facebook alloc] init];
m_FacebookUploader = [[FBVideoUpload alloc]init]; 
NSArray *permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil];
m_Facebook.forceOldStyleAuth = YES;
[m_Facebook authorize:APP_ID permissions:permissions delegate:self];
```

In Facebook delegate methods

```
- (void)fbDidLogin
{
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:m_MoviePath];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Look at my funny video !", @"title",
                            [@"A message" objectForKey:@"message"], @"description",
                            nil];

    [m_FacebookUploader setApiKey:APP_ID];
    [m_FacebookUploader setAccessToken:m_Facebook.accessToken];
    [m_FacebookUploader setAppSecret:APP_SECRET];
    [m_FacebookUploader startUploadWithURL:movieURL params:params delegate:self];

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. Actually, the problem was that my Facebook app was not set to "Desktop" mode. I should have updated this post.